# Regex to get phrase after spaces and before match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a phrase before a certain text, I've only been able to get the word or the entire line. I want to get the entire phrase that is between the matched text on the right and the several spaces that are on the left. Not sure if it'll be obvious once it is posted but there are multiple tabs/spaces between the date and TPL TO RENTAL.

```
Sales Packet Review Checklist
    Date:           January 6.2022      TPL TO RENTAL   Type of Sales Packet
```

Trying to get TPL TO RENTAL based on 'Type of Sales Packet'

```
([\w]*.?\s{2,})Type
```

Can only get RENTAL using this and not TPL TO RENTAL

Comment: const text = "Sales Packet Review Checklist Date: January 6.2022 TPL TO RENTAL Type of Sales Packet";
const regex = new RegExp(/(.*)\s{2,}Type/);
const match = text.match(regex);
const phrase = match[1]; // "TPL TO RENTAL"

Comment: Like this? `(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)\s{2,}Type\b` https://regex101.com/r/IxXxNt/1

Comment: Yes that's getting me exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group matching 1 or more non whitespace characters using `\S+` (or word characters `\w+`) followed by repeating the same with a single space or whitespace character in between.

```
(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)\s{2,}Type\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\S+(?:\s\S+)*` Match 1+ non whitespace characters, and optionally repeat the same with a single whitespace character
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s{2,}Type\b` Match 2 or more whitespace characters followed by `Type` and a word boundary

See the capture group value at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IxXxNt/1) .